# warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_python_module_name' specified multiple times; using first specification

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++, cython

I created some `Cython` files, and import them in a `Python` file using,

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()

import Cython_Mod1
import Cython_Mod2
```

When I run the `py` file, the `C` compiler (`VC++14`) generated the following errors

```
Cython_Mod1.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_Cython_Mod1' specified multiple times; using first specification
```

for each `Cython`module.

How to fix this and does it affect the performance or can be erroneous in the execution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`LNK4197`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/835326) is a warning, as such it shouldn't affect the compilation of your `.c` files, `Cython` probably just generates code that exports that function multiple times (for good reasons, I'd assume).

Since `PyInit_<modname>` is responsible for initializing the module; if your modules get initialized and imported correctly you have no issues. It won't affect the performance and/or result in erroneous execution.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jim's answer states it is only a (relatively benign) warning and can be ignored.

However, this answer presents more information and a fix.

---

When Python interpreter loads an extension/dll, module's init-function (e.g. `PyInit_Cython_Mod1`) must be visible/exported.

Cython uses macro [`PyMODINIT_FUNC`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b60f64e4343913b4931dc27379d9808e5b78fe1/Include/pyport.h#L670) to mark the init-function, which is defined as

```c
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL PyObject*
```

with [`Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b60f64e4343913b4931dc27379d9808e5b78fe1/Include/exports.h#L6) being marked as visible/exported on Windows:

```c
#define Py_EXPORTED_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)
```

Thus, there is no need to export the symbol via linker options in the command line.

However, probably due to historical reasons, `distutils` plays safe and exports the init-symbol also via `/EXPORT:`-linker options, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55aabee07501e1468082b3237620e4ecd75c5da6/Lib/distutils/_msvccompiler.py#L506):

```
...
export_opts = ["/EXPORT:" + sym for sym in (export_symbols or [])]
...
```

`export_symbols` are calculated by [`get_export_symbols`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/distutils/command/build_ext.py#L684):

```
def get_export_symbols(self, ext):
    """Return the list of symbols that a shared extension has to
    export.  This either uses 'ext.export_symbols' or, if it's not
    provided, "PyInit_" + module_name.  Only relevant on Windows, where
    the .pyd file (DLL) must export the module "PyInit_" function.
    """
    initfunc_name = "PyInit_" + ext.name.split('.')[-1]
    if initfunc_name not in ext.export_symbols:
        ext.export_symbols.append(initfunc_name)
    return ext.export_symbols
```

However, because we don't need any symbols being exported via linker-option, we could override this method as follows:

```
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
def get_export_symbols_fixed(self, ext):
    return []

# replace wrong version with the fixed:
build_ext.get_export_symbols = get_export_symbols_fixed

import pyximport
pyximport.install()
...
```

No warning this time!