# Statically link python37.dll and vcruntime140.dll when using cython --embed

Tags: python, visual-c++, dll, cython, cl

Let's say I'm "cythonizing" this `test.py`:

```
import json
print(json.dumps({'key': 'hello world'}))
```

with:

```
cython test.py --embed
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cl test.c /I C:\Python37\include /link C:\Python37\libs\python37.lib
```

As mentioned in [Minimal set of files required to distribute an embed-Cython-compiled code and make it work on any machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390978/minimal-set-of-files-required-to-distribute-an-embed-cython-compiled-code-and-ma/62392087#62392087), it is necessary to distribute `python37.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` and the content of `Lib\` (either as `Lib\` or packed into a `python37.zip`) as well, along the `test.exe` file.

**Question: How to modify the `cl.exe ...` command to ask the compiler to statically link `python37.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` inside the `test.exe` file?**

(so that shipping `python37.dll` and `vcruntime140.dll` separately is no longer necessary)

Comment: See [Building Python Statically](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically) and links therein.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks. Does this mean it implies to rebuild Python completely? I can imagine this takes a lot of time? (The last link on this page is 404, sadly). A detailed tutorial for Windows would be interesting (with `cl.exe` instead of gcc, etc.)

Comment: My understanding is "yes" though I didn't try it first hand. A cached copy of the broken link is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190124012917/http://mdqinc.com/blog/2011/08/statically-linking-python-with-cython-generated-modules-and-packages/).

Comment: vcruntime is quite straightforward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36270902/5769463. Statically linked python on windows is somewhat more complicated than on linux

Comment: Thanks @ead I'll first start with vcruntime. How would you do it from command line with cl.exe? Just add /MT ? This seems too simple to be true :) as I don't use the MSVC++ IDE I need to do it from cl.exe

Comment: Linking statically vcruntime alone would not bring much: python dll would still depend on runtime-dll and you would end up with violation of ODR and subtle problems.

Comment: @ead What is ODR? By just out of curiosity, how would you do the equivalent of adding `/MT` in `/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library`, but from cl.exe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Remark:** [There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72476752/5769463) is probably a better/saner/easier option than the one presented in bellow.

The main difference between these two approaches: while in this approach all C-extension must be backed in into the resulting executable, in the alternative approach C-extension are compiled separately or an additional C-extension could also be added  later on to the distribution.

---

While creating a statically linked embeded-Python-executable is relatively easy on Linux (see for example this [SO-post](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/48836737/5769463)) it is much more complicated on Windows. And you probably don't want to do it.

Also the result might not be what one would expect: Due to limitations of dlls compared to Linux' shared objects, the resulting static python-version will not be able to use/load any other c-extensions, as the one backed-in during the compile/link time (Note: this is not entirely true, a workaround is presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72476752/5769463)).

I also would not recommend to switch from vcruntime-dll to its static version - it would only make sense, when **everything** (exe, c-extensions, other dll which depend on vcruntime) is statically linked into one huge executable.

The first stumbling block: While on Linux python distributions often have a static Python-library already shipped, Windows distributions have only the dll, which cannot be statically linked in.

Thus one needs to build a static library on Windows. A good starting point is this [link](https://cpython-core-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_cpython_windows.html).

After downloading the source  for the right Python version (`git clone --depth=1 --branch v3.8.0 https://github.com/python/cpython.git`) you can go to `cpython\PCBuild` and build cpython as explained in documentation (which might vary from version to version).

In my case it was

```
cd cpython/PCbuild
.\build.bat -e -p x64
```

No we have a functioning Python3.8 installation, which can be found in `cpython/PCbuild/amd64`. Create folder `cpython/PCbuild/static_amd64` and add the following pyx-file:

```
#hello.pyx
print("I'm standalone")
```

copy `python38.dll` to `static_amd64` for the time being.

Now let's build our program with embedded python interpreter:

```
cython --embed -3 hello.pyx
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
cl /c hello.c /Fohello.obj  /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I<path_to_code>\cpython\include -I<path_to_code>\cpython\PC
link hello.obj python38.lib  /OUT:hello_prog.exe /nologo "/LIBPATH:<path_to_code>\cpython\PCbuild\amd64"
```

After the start, `hello_prog.exe` lies to us, as it is not really standalone. The good news is: it finds the Python-installation which is needed as described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56861396/5769463).

Now let's create a static python38-library. For that we open `pcbuild.sln` in cpython/PCbuild-folder and change `pythoncore`-project's setting to produce static library in `PCbuild\amd64_static`-folder.  Rebuild it.

Now we can build the embedded-python-exe:

```
cl /c hello.c /Fohello.obj /D "Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED" /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I<path_to_code>\cpython\include -I<path_to_code>\cpython\PC
link hello.obj python38.lib "version.lib" "shlwapi.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /OUT:hello_prog.exe /nologo "/LIBPATH:<path_to_code>\cpython\PCbuild\static_amd64"
```

Compared to the build against dll we had to change the following:

- [`Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d4fe098d1ee4f4056ac65cae55f5ffdd439dede0/PC/pyconfig.h#L255) (i.e. `/D "Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED"`) is added to preprocessor definitions, otherwise the linker will look for wrong symbols.
- the Windows dependencies (i.e. `version.lib` and so on) which were brought by the python-dll need to be passed to the linker explicitly now (this can be looked up in the linker-command-line of the pythoncore-project).
- lib path show to the static folder, i.e. `"/LIBPATH:<path_to_code>\cpython\PCbuild\static_amd64"` now.
- there might be other smaller troubles (different optimization levels, link-time-code generation, disabling whole-program-optimization and so on) depending on your exact tool chain.

We can delete the `python38.dll` from `static_amd64` now and the `hello_prog.exe` still works.

On Linux, this would be "mission accomplished", on Windows we are just at the beginning...

Make sure that `cpython`-folder has a `DLLs`-folder with all right pyd-files, otherwise create and copy all pyd-files from `PCbuild/amd64`-folder.

Let's make our pyx-file a little bit more complicated:

```
import _decimal
print("I'm standalone")
```

`_decimal` is a fast implementation of the `decimal`-module which is a C-extension and can be found in the  `DLL`-folder.

After cythonizing and building it, running `hello_prog.exe` leads to the following error message:

```
import _decimal
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _decimal: The specified module could not be found.
```

The problem is easy to find:

```
dumpbin /DEPENDENTS ../amd64/_decimal.pyd
...
python38.dll
...
```

The extensions of our installation still depends on the python-dll. Let's rebuild them against the static library - we need to change library path to from `amd64` to `static_amd64`,  to add preprocessor define `Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED` and all missing windows-libraries (i.e ""version.lib"& Co.) and adding `/EXPORT:PyInit__decimal` to link options, otherwise, due to `Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED` it [becomes invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866779/5769463). The result has no dependency on the python-dll! We copy it to the DLLs-folder and ...

```
hello_prog.exe
# crash/stopped worked
```

What is happening? We violated one definition rule (ODR) and ended up with two Python-interpreters: the one from the `hello_prog.exe`, which is initialized and the one from `_decimal.pyd` which is not initialized. `_decimal.pyd` "speaks" to its interpreter which is not initialized and bad things happens.

The difference to Linux is the difference between shared-objects and dlls: while shared-objects can use symbols from the exe (if the exe is built with right options) dll cannot and thus must either depend on a dll (which we don't want)  or need to have its own version.

To avoid the violation of ODR we have only one way out: it must be linked directly into our `hello_word`-executable. So let's change the project for `_decimal` to static library and rebuild it in `static_amd64`-folder. Deleting the pyd from "DLLs"-folder and adding `/WHOLEARCHIVE:_decimal.lib` to the linker-command-line (whole archive while otherwise the linker would just discard `_decimal.lib` as none of its symbols is referenced somewhere), leads to an executable, which has the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_decimal'
```

This is expected - we need to tell to the interpreter, that the module `_decimal` is backed in and should not be searched on the python path.

The usual solution for this problem is to use [`PyImport_AppendInittab`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_AppendInittab) just before `Py_Initialize`, that means we need to change the c-file generated by cython (there might be [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52698794/5769463),  but due to [multi-phase initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669343/5769463) it is not that easy. So probably a saner way to embed Python is the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669343/5769463) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424720/5769463) were `main` isn't written by Cython). The c-file should look as follows:

```
//decalare init-functions
extern  PyObject* PyInit__decimal();
...
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
...
    if (argc && argv)
        Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    PyImport_AppendInittab("_decimal", PyInit__decimal); //  HERE WE GO
                                                         //  BEFORE Py_Initialize
    
    Py_Initialize();
```

Building everything now leads to an exe which prints

```
I'm standalone
```

and this time it is not lying to us!

Now we have to repeat the last steps for all other built-in extension we need.

---

The above means there are some restrictions for statically built python-interpreter: All built-in modules need to be backed into the executable and we cannot extend the interpreter latter on with libraries like numpy/scipy (but can to do it directly at the compile/link time).

---

Getting rid of vcruntime-dll is easier: all above steps must be done [with `/MT` option instead of  `MD`-option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36270902/5769463).  However, there might be some problems due to usage of other dlls (e.g. `_ctypes` needs `ffi`-dll)  which where built with the dll-version (and thus we once again have ODR-violated) - so I would not recommend it.

Comment: What if you try it "similar" to the Linux way. Link the static python lib to your executable, so this executable exports all the python functions? Of course the extensions then also have to "link" to your executable instead of the python dll, and so you can only use it for this one executable.

Comment: @ssbssa the issue is, that there is no -Xlinker -export-dynamic for MSVC, this is the reason the python exe is just a wrapper of the dll and you need to link c-extensions against it - one cannot link against an exe. It might work when compiled with gcc-ports: I didn’t try it.

Comment: Yes, you can. And I think MSVC even automatically creates an import library if the executable has any exported functions.

Comment: @ssvssa could you provide a link? Never saw somebody do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what links you want. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15468775/1983398) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24796678/1983398)? There are definitely people who have done that (me included).

Comment: @ssbssa it amazing when it works and surely not the most standard way of doing it (the usual way is to create a dll and an exe wrapper as cpython does).

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly different approach (as suggested by @ssbssa's comments): the main difference is that with this version, one can add further C-extensions later on and doesn't have to back them in into the resulting executable.

The first steps until the creation of `hello_prog.exe` linked against static python-library are the same as in [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62524995/5769463). The command

```
...
link hello.obj ... /OUT:hello_prog.exe ...
```

creates not only the the exe itself, but also the lib-file `hello_prob.lib`. This lib-file can be used for linkage, because exe itself exports a lot of symbols from Python-library. The behavior is similar to `-Xlinker -export-dynamic`behavior when linking embedded python executable on Linux.

Now, when C-extensions are built (e.g. `_decimal` we need to add `hello_prog.lib` as linking dependency (i.e. in Properties/Linker/Input->Additional Dependencies).

When we look at the run time dependencies of  `_decimal.pyd`, we see:

```
dumpbin /DEPENDENTS _decimal.pyd
...
Dump of file _decimal.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    hello_prog.exe
    ...
```

When the resulting pyds are linked in such a way and can be found by the embedded interperter, we run `hello_prog` and see:

```
I'm standalone
```

which means everything works as expected.

Should further C-extension be built, `hello_prob.lib`-file must be provided/stored somewhere.